# SSIS Package to restore

Tags: java, c#, sql, vb.net, msbi

I have a requirement to create SSIS package to restore .bak files and while restoring, package have to shrink .mdf files?will the package fulfil the requirement?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to use SSIS as it can be done by T-SQL? How many databases do your process involves? Explain your process.

Comment: 150 databases involves. Instead of SQL we need SSIS package. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no any task for Database restore in SSIS. However, you can take help of LOOP and Script task to make it.

http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/automate-database-restore-to-remote/

You can use the SHRINK DATABASE TASK to shrink the databases. It uses the command `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE` that can be implemented in previous approach as well.

Comment: Thanks. is there any stored procedure to restore database, I am not familiar with coding.

Comment: No, there is no system SP to restore db. you can create your own.
Refer: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11308/automating-a-database-backup-restore-and-stored-proc-call